# "sell_seat()" function getting skipped over

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm in the last part of a C++ online course and having difficulty with one of my labs. The lab describes writing a program that lets the user know of available and sold tickets for a theater.

The output for the code should be:

> AA 101 sold

> AA 102 available

However, I continue to receive an output of:

> AA 101

> AA 102 available

When running the program through a debugger in VS Code, I noticed that the 'sell_seat'() function is skipped over when it evaluates "if(!myticket1.is_sold())".

Removing the exclamation point in front of "myticket1.is_sold()" gives the right output but does not solve the problem.

Where did I go wrong in my code?

The prerequisites in the lab:

> The class should contain fields for the row, seat number, and whether
> the ticket has been sold or not. Define a constructor which accepts as
> arguments the row and seat number and sets the sold status to false in
> the constructor initialization section.
>
> Include the following member functions:
>
> ```
> A function to check if the ticket has been sold with this signature: bool is_sold();
> A function to update the ticket status to sold with this signature:  void sell_seat();
> A function to print the row, seat number, and sold status delimited by a space with this signature: string print_ticket();
> ```

**ShowTicket Class**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ShowTicket {
public:
    string row;
    string seatNum;
    string status;

    bool is_sold();
    void sell_seat();
    string print_ticket();

    ShowTicket(string sRow, string Num) {
        row = sRow;
        seatNum = Num;
    }
};

bool ShowTicket::is_sold() {
    if (row == "AA" && seatNum == "101") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
void ShowTicket::sell_seat() {
    if (is_sold()) {
        status = "sold";
    }
    else {
        status = "available";
    }
}
string ShowTicket::print_ticket() {
    return row + " " + seatNum + " " + status;
}
```

**Main function**

```
int main() {
    ShowTicket myticket1("AA", "101");
    ShowTicket myticket2("AA", "102");

    // The sell_seat function is skipped for myticket1, causing the issue
    if (!myticket1.is_sold()) {
        myticket1.sell_seat();
    }
    if (!myticket2.is_sold()) {
        myticket2.sell_seat();
    }

    cout << myticket1.print_ticket() << endl;
    cout << myticket2.print_ticket() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the results of your debugging session where you use a debugger to single step through your code and watch variables?

Comment: Is there any reason you have the seat *number* as a string?

Comment: Since there are two states for a seat, sold and available, you could make the status a `bool` type.

Comment: Looks to me like the `ShowTicket` constructor sets the row and seat number  to AA and 101, so the results of `if (row == "AA" && seatNum == "101")` are utterly predictable.  I think you need to explain your intent here a bit better.

Comment: The seat number is specified as a *string* since the lab has us giving the parameters "AA" and "101".

Comment: to be honest I'd consider storing the seat number as a string. The number's not being used in any math, so it's more an abstract symbol. String will allow seat numbers like 001, which may be useful. And might not be useful. Depends on the use case.

Comment: Think of the seats belonging to a grid or matrix.  The letters are the row ordinate and the number is the column ordinate.  If your ticket belongs to only one seat (in the entire theatre), the seat is sold otherwise the seat is available.  So, what happens if I have a different seat number, like 102, is that seat sold or available?  Your code says it's available (not sold), which brings up a question, how does one sell a ticket to a seat other than <"AA", "101">, like <"AA", "99">?

Comment: I would change the `is_sold` to:  `return status == "sold";`.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: In general, when you have code that looks like `if (condition) return true; else return false;`, you can simplify to `return condition;`

Comment: Adding 'return status == "sold";' prevents the skip from happening when I ran the code and checked through debug.  However the output now comes out "AA 101 available AA 102 available"

Comment: Think about the logic in your `sell_seat` function, and the after effects from selling a seat.  In most real-world scenarios, if a seat is sold (already), you can't sell it.  If your seat is available, then selling a seat would change its status to "sold", or would it?

Comment: Think about how a theatre would make seats available.  Presently, you don't have an algorithm to change a seat that was sold to make it available.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The lab does not specify coding a algorithm to change seats from sold to available. I've add the directions given in the lab if that helps

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you have to provide the prerequisites in the lab, then you have not done enough research to produce a [mre]. Step through your code with a debugger to see where the execution flow or data values differ from your expectations. Identifying `myticket1.is_sold()` as a suspect is a good first step, but it's only a first step. Dig into `is_sold()` to see what is going on there. If that looks good, dig into `sell_seat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first if statement, the function is never entered because the is_sold function returns true. You're using the not operator, so the statement is evaluated as false.

Therefore the status never updates and that's why it's blank.

```
bool ShowTicket::is_sold() {
   return (row == "AA" && seatNum = "101"); //simplified
}

//even better, you can use the is sold to call the function that checks the condition

bool ShowTicket::is_sold() {
   bool sold = false; //will return false if the condition is not met.
   if (row == "AA" && seatNum = "101") {
       sell_seat();
       sold = true;
   }
   return sold;
}

//Lastly, update the sell_seat function to do the granular task of selling the ticket

void sell_seat() {
    status = "sold";
    std::cout << "Sold ticket#: " << seatNum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: After taking my dog for a walk, I realized I was overcomplicating things. I'll give your suggestions a shot tomorrow since I'm a bit pooped :p

Comment: Please review your `seatNum = "101"` in your answer.  There could be a typo there.